# Cross Domain issue while working with WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, cors, jquery-ajaxq

I have tried different approached but its not working for me.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load WEBAPI URL.

> The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*,
>   CLIENT URL', but only one is allowed. Origin 'CLIENT URL' is therefore
>   not allowed access.

this is the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this: [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)
Your client must be allowed to do CORS, so you can use 
a placeholder like

> "*"

to allow all clients, or explicitly by setting

> "www.YourAllowedClientDomain.com"

in the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" response header of your web api.

for example:

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://api.bob.com

To make this work in Web API you have to configure it at startup.

For example:

public static class WebApiConfig
{

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("https://client1.com,https://www.Client2.com", "*", "*");
    //To enable cross - origin requests, add the[EnableCors] attribute to your Web API controller or controller method:
    config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Only one value is allowed!